# GPU Compute Units?

Tags: opencl, gpu, gpgpu

Hello as i read on OpenCL docs ,
Compute Unit has many processing elements.
Is processing element contains only ALU ?
on the processing element , is single ALU have SIMD operation ? or 4 ALU can make SIMD ?

Answer (score 1):

I think most current devices map a single ALU to a processing element, and an ALU is a single SIMD core. Indeed, CPUs that don't support SIMD are not OpenCL compatible.

The thing about OpenCL is that you don't need to be concerned about the exact underlying architecture unless you are writing a kernel for very specific hardware. Devices in the future could use as many schedulers/ALUs/memory controllers/etc as the manufacturer chooses to implement the SIMD architecture.

If you want to follow the "write once, run anywhere" mantra, you need to stick to the properties exposed by the OpenCL API. (eg CL_KERNEL_PREFERRED_WORK_GROUP_SIZE_MULTIPLE, and CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_*)

Comment: I would say that the important measures are: `CL_KERNEL_PREFERRED_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE`, then you have some minor things to take care of like: dimensions, local memory, max args, max arg sizes, max constant, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Some had shared special function units per several ALUs and some had equal amount of FPU per ALU without any special unit there are addressing units, scalar units too. SIMD organization is different between AMD and NVIDIA and INTEL. Some have 16-wide some have 32-wide groups. Then those groups join together to make a 64-wide compute unit for one of those producers while 192 for another producer. What those ALUs do is generally altered by driver optimizations. You just write single instruction - multiple data code and driver takes care of optimizations unless you choose a optimization-killing execution argument.

You can query necessary info by using opencl api methods.